# AssemblyNameReference class does not exist, what is the replacement?

Tags: .net, roslyn

I'm checking the Roslyn API using 'Getting Started: Semantic Analysis' walkthrough.
There's a part in it which tries to add a reference to the compilation:

```
var compilation = Compilation.Create("HelloWorld")
                         .AddReferences(new AssemblyNameReference("mscorlib"))
                         .AddSyntaxTrees(tree);
```

But it seems the API is changed and the 'AssemblyNameReference' does not exist anymore.
Or may the document is wrong, because naming of 'AddReferences' tells that it needs some sort of IEnumerable.

BTW, I'm looking for the correct implementation so I could test it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The September 2012 version of the Semantic Analysis (CSharp) walkthrough contains this code:

```
var compilation = Compilation.Create("HelloWorld")
                         .AddReferences(MetadataReference.CreateAssemblyReference("mscorlib"))
                         .AddSyntaxTrees(tree);
```

You are probably looking at a version of the walkthrough from an earlier CTP. Try using static factory methods on MetadataReference.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I downloaded it from the Roslyn page. But seems I did something wrong.

Comment: I've just checked http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx and the documents for C# language is still titled for June 2012.

Comment: Oops, that's bad. Which documents exactly are wrong? I'll send e-mails to get them fixed.

Comment: @Jason the out of date links which misleads me are:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx (all walkthrough links)
and 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27745

But I found the up to date versions somewhere on my local machine where Roslyn is installed.